# get image path from html using php from any kind of image tag

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am trying to create a function to extract one image from HTML snippet but not only for **img** tag, I want to do it for almost all posible configurations, for example, if I pass any of thus HTML snippet, the function must to give me the URL for one image (any one):

HTML 1

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600"> (this is the easy)
```

HTML 2

```
<div class="bg-img attachment-homepage-sml-thumb size-homepage-sml-thumb lazyloaded" data-bg="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/img_pink_flowers.webp" style="background-image: url('https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/img_pink_flowers.webp');"></div>
```

HTML 3

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

HTML 4

```
<picture loading="lazy" class="wp-image-204 size-medium aligncenter">
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg.webp 270w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg.webp 45w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg.webp 629w" sizes="(max-width: 270px) 100vw, 270px">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg" alt="" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg 270w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers-45x50.jpg 45w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_pink_flowers.jpg 629w" sizes="(max-width: 270px) 100vw, 270px" width="270" height="300">
</picture>
```

For IMG tag I have no problem and I don't want to create a custom script for each possible HTML, I think there must to be simple.
I have no code right now because, only for IMG.
Thank you very much

Comment: You say “IMG tag” but then show other types of tags, too. Instead, for a given block of HTML, you want to find at least one thing that resolves to something that is an image, be it a JPEG, GIF, PNG, SVG, WEBP, is that right? What about `<span fake="example.jpg"/ >` or `<img src="index.html"/>`?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: There really is no general way to do this. You could write a rule that catches some/many/most, or, if you have a known data set you could tweak it to catch many/most. For instance, you could assume that all images have a certain file extension and backtrack until you found a quote or equal sign (html) or colon (css). You'll want to handle base64 and inline SVG somehow, too, possibly. You could instead fire up a headless browser and see what's in there.